# "We're stuck between floors two and three". Is the definite article implied?

Tags: definite-article, word-in-context, ordinals

When you name the floor you're on, you say "I'm on the [an ordinal number] floor.", which totally makes sense!

So why do people, for example, say "We're stuck between floors two and three"?

Do they imply the definite article in front of "floors" but omit it due to laziness?

Comment: Phrased like that, I would also say "I am on floor two" and not "I am on the floor two." It's just the way it is said. If it were laziness, we wouldn't bother with *any* articles.

Comment: @WeatherVane does it mean two options exist - "I am on floor two" and "I am on the second floor"?

Comment: That's right, but as @pboss3010 pointed out below, there can be confusion as to *which* is the "second floor". USA and UK have different floor numbering.

Comment: Oh, I remember. The UK's first floor is called "the ground floor", is that right?

Comment: Yes, in USA the "first floor" is at ground level, in UK it is the one above the ground floor, and in the lifts (elevators) there is a G button. But if you refer to the **label** on the floor, there's no confusion.

Comment: Because the person is **between floors**, plural. The floors just happen to be two and three.

Comment: The definite article is not omitted due to laziness. It is omitted correctly. It is *incorrect* to put it here. Yes, "the second floor", but *never* "the floor two"

Answer (score 19):

I don't think there is such a thing as "laziness" in grammar. You can't just omit things in the middle of a sentence because you feel lazy and have a grammatically correct sentence.

The reason why *floors 2 and 3* is used without an article is because in English we usually don't use definite articles in front of things that have numbers following them. That's a well-known fact. For example, when you're staying at a hotel, you would say this when talking about rooms:

> I'm staying in **room #35**.

One way to think about this is that the number 35 uniquely identifies the room you're talking about and *35* (or *35th*) is not being used as an adjective describing the room like in the example down below where you would need a definite article:

> the **35th** room

Again, just think of *35th* as an adjective describing a specific room that you have in mind.

Comment: Room 35, door 9, car 54, boat 6.

Comment: Further to this, given the potential for odd labeling of floors, saying "between floor 2 and floor 3" specifies you mean the floors labeled 2 and 3, ignoring potential confusion of what exactly is the second floor.

Comment: Size 10 shoes or "a size 10 shoes". I've seen "a size 10", "a size Large" somewhere . Why is there indefinite articles? Can they be omitted? And what would it mean?

Comment: It should be **size-10 shoes** (you don't necessarily need a hyphen, but you can have it there for more clarity if you want to).  *Size-10* is acting as an adjective that describes the shoes that you're talking about. *A size-10 shoes* is grammatically wrong because the article *a* is supposed to go with *shoes* (*size-10* is an adjective describing the shoes as I said), but *shoes* is plural! That's just wrong grammar. **A size-10** is really just the abbreviation for **a pair of size-10 shoes**. That's why an article appears in front of *size-10*. That's how I understand all this.

Comment: You could have "a size-10 shoe", referring to a single shoe.

Comment: "What's your shoe size?" - "I wear (a) size-10 shoes", "I saw a dress in  (a) size-12", "I'm (a) size-Large", "She's (a) size medium", "I'm looking for a sweater in (a) size Large?" Is putting the indefinite articles incorrect here?

Comment: @MichaelRybkin "I'm a Large" is it wrong? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231051/meaning-of-im-a-large

Why is there an "a" in front of a t-shirt size?

Comment: @Rusletov Well, I think they did a pretty good job explaining what it means in the answer as well as in the comments section. I don't know much about clothing sizes, but **I'm a Large** would basically mean that when it comes to shirts whose sizes are "Large", that's what I wear. So, I'm a Large. I wear size-Large T-shirts. For shoes, you could say **I wear size-10 shoes** or **I wear a size-10** or even **I'm a size-10** depending on the context.

Comment: "Room 35" would be if the room is actually /labeled/ "35". You would rarely say "the 35th room", as no one likes to count that high for ordinals (too easy to lose track and miscount). "Boat 6" and "the 6th boat" could be interchangeable, if it's clear to see that there is a sign "Boat 6" /or/ it's easy to count boats 1, 2, 3,... up to the 6th. In general, if there is a sign for the room (or boat or floor) number, use that to avoid miscounting or accidentally using a different convention (e.g., "Ground floor" versus "1st floor" versus "Floor 1").

Answer (score 9):

- We were **between floors** when the elevator broke down. [i.e. not specific and plural]

No *the.* idiom: **to be between two things** in the plural.

However, if you then want to be **specific**, you would say:

- We were **between floors 2 and 3** when the elevator broke down.

BUT:

We were between **the 2nd and 3rd floors** when the elevator broke down.

- We were between two jobs when we got the call.
- We were between two major highways on a side road.

A plural noun after *between* does not require *the* before the noun.

However, you could say: We were between the two floors [if the floors have already been mentioned; the floors in question] when the elevator broke down.

Comment: The focus on *between* in this answer is misleading — *between* is irrelevant here.  The issue is just the difference between *floor two* (cardinal number after noun, no article) and *the second floor* (ordinal number before noun, definite article).

Comment: @PLL Notice to tenants: **Second floor** apartments will be painted next week.

Answer (score 4):

You confusion here is that you're not properly differentiating between what it means to be on "the 4th floor" vs. being on "floor 4".

Being on "floor 4" means you are on the floor named/labeled "4". The name of it is "floor 4".

Being on "the 4th floor" means you're on the floor that is the 4th one.

For floors these things typically coincide, so we use the ways of saying it interchangeably. But the grammar difference between the two concepts is what you're noticing.